# Kendo UI Grid: I lose pagination after datasource refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, pagination, kendo-grid

I have this definition in a cshtml file:

```
@{Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderItem>()
    .Name("OrderList")                                            
    .Columns(columns => {
                       .........
                    })
    .DataSource(binding => binding
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(14)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.No))
        .Read(read => read.Action("SearchSalesOrder", "SalesOrder"))        
    )
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Render();
}
```

In the controller I use `.ToDataSourceResult(request)` and it works perfectly (the grid has pagination). The problem appears when I have to change the datasource. This occurs because the user can filter, search... I call by Ajax to the same method "SearchSalesOrder" with more parameters. Using Javascript, I take the json from the response and I change the datasource in this way:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: result.Data,
    pageSize: 14
});
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
grid.refresh();
```

After that, the pager only shows one page. I'd need to change the datasource keeping the pagination.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it.
It was very simple. I had to add the `total` attribute in the `schema`. Basically in Javascript, when I need to change the datasource, I have this code:

```
var grid = $("#OrderList").data("kendoGrid");
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
                url: '/Sales/SearchSalesOrder',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    page: 1, pageSize: 14, startDate: startDateParam, endDate: endDateParam,.....
                }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 14,
    serverPaging: true,
    schema: {
        parse: function (response) {
            // Charts refresh
            .......

            return response.Data;
        },
        total: function (response) {
            return response.Total;
        },
        data: "Data"
    }
});
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
grid.refresh();
```

It works.
:)

Comment: It works, if we want refresh or change grid's datasource we must set Total option. and while we use pagination feature we should set Total options as well.